# Magento - Is it possible to attach a xlsx file to a transactional email?

Tags: magento-1.8

Currently i attach CSV file in transaction mail.

my code is

```
 $transactionalEmail->getMail()->createAttachment($string,'text/UTF-8')->filename = 'order_'.$report_date.'.csv';
```

but want to send xlxs file transaction email

i used

```
 $transactionalEmail->getMail()->createAttachment($string,'text/UTF-8')->filename = 'order_'.$report_date.'.xlxs';
```

xlxs file attached in mail but didn't open properly.

please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Actually CSV maintains a very basic structure (only comma separated) to store tabular data, but in case of Excel it stores the data more superior way with all the Formatting (fonts, colors, sizes).

So, you need to use separate coding to convert your CSV into xlsx. Following links could help you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612888/converting-csv-file-to-xlsx
- http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/40495.html

Normally Excel opens the CSV file as well, so, if you are not in absolute need for excel format, then CSV is a good format to use!